# configurationproperties is an unknown property

Tags: mysql, spring, eclipse

I am having problem understanding the usage of @ConfigurationProperties. In my application properties file, all of the variables "is an unknown property" with yellow underline. I run the application but the same thing happens. Is there a way to link the configuration at application.properties to my datasource function?

If I use

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/trs?useSSL=false
```

it works just fine but it i use app.datasource.url it wouldn't work

My application.properties file

```
# Primary DataSource configuration
app.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/trs?useSSL=false
app.datasource.username=user    
app.datasource.password=pass
```

my primary .java file

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="app.datasource")
@Primary
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    final DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/trs?useSSL=false");
    dataSource.setUsername("user");
    dataSource.setPassword("pass");
    return dataSource;
}
```

Comment: what is the problem here. Are you not able to start your application or is it that you see some error messages in your IDE

Answer (score 0):

For your application.properties, you need a corresponding java class to load the configuration in a bean. Like this -

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="app.datasource")
@Component
public class DataSourceConfig{
   private String url;
   private String username;
   private String password;
...
}
```

Now, where you want to use the **DataSourceConfig** bean, you can inject like this,

```
@Autowired
DataSourceConfig dataSourceConfig;
```

And once you have the object just do,

```
dataSourceConfig.getUrl();
dataSourceConfig.getUsername();
dataSourceConfig.getPassword();
```